# ClassNotFoundException spark submit yarn

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, sbt, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark program (scala).

I run command assembly to get a jar.

I put the jar on `hdfs` cluster (so the jar is physically on the server)

I run the command `jar -tvf` to be sure my main class is in the jar (and it is: `com/mycompany/MyMainClass.class`

I try to run the following command on a server of my cluster 
`./hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit --class com.mycompany.MyMainClass --master yarn project.jar`

and I have this error:

```
Failed to load com.mycompany.MyMainClass.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.MyMainClass
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: version of scala 2.12

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole path in the jar argument
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

It was because of assembly in sbt for scala, this is the correct mergeStrategy for me

```
`assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}`
```